# What am I doing wrong in this Serializable attempt

Tags: java, serialization

I'm trying to store some objects for future processing in event of network failure.
I have an array of NameValuePairs in a Serializeable class... I've eliminated everything else, and still I'm getting a NotSerializeableException... I've never tried to write a Serializeable object to file before... I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but can't see what it is...

```
public void store(){
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;          
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Upload failed, saving file to " + path + "/" + fileName);
        File f = new File(path);
        if(!f.exists()){
            try{
            (new File(path)).mkdirs();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, "failed to create directory " + path );
            }
        }
        f = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        Parts p = new Parts(parts);
        out.writeObject(p); //THIS IS THE LINE WHERE IT DIES WITH THAT EXCEPTION
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "FAILED TO SAVE file: " + path + "/" + fileName );
        Log.d(TAG, "error:" + e);
    }   catch(Exception e){     
        Log.d(TAG, "error:" + e);
    }
}

private class Parts implements Serializable{        
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7603433209073871781L;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public NameValuePair [] p;
    public Parts(NameValuePair [] parts){
        this.p = parts;
    }       
}
```

Comment: What is going into the NameValuePair?  Maybe a value that isn't serializable?

Comment: Try creating a standalone program that does this. It looks like the problrm is with what you are putting into the NameValuePair. everything contained within your objects need to be Serializable.

Comment: No, they're all strings of one kind or another... is there any illegal value I should be looking for?

Comment: Can you post the class definition of NameValuePair ? @Steve Kuo is probably right and its probably not defined as Serializable.

Comment: I assumed this is what was being used:  
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/NameValuePair.html

This class is serializable, so it seems like something down the object graph somewhere.  I've also never done serialization using a private class, but I don't know of any rules specifically against it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object is serializable if it implements `Serializable` and all of its non-transient and non-static fields are serializable. Is your `NameValuePair` serializable?

Follow-up: Looking at the [docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/NameValuePair.html), `NameValuePair` implements `Serializable`. Also `String[]` is serializable. What is the exception you're seeing?

Comment: Ah... I see what you're saying... It's not "my" NameValuePair... it's org.apache.commons.httpClient.NameValuePair, and I have to assume it's not... Before I go and copy all its innards into a regular Hash, are Hashes Serializable? I know Vectors are, but they're ugly :)

Comment: hmm... I've modified my Parts object (altering my question in the process... no improvement. Fails in the same place... is String [] not Serializable? If not... then what is?!

Answer (score 0):

You may need default constructor in Parts.

Comment: Parameter-less constructor is not required for serialization.